# Any one please help, I'm practicing listening on inglorious bastard

Tags: listening-comprehension

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aB25iT3LBnU&t=4s
Could you please advise what they speak in 0.48 - 1.00?
I could not catch up at all.

Comment: I voted to close this question, because what we are asked to do can be simply solved by switching on the subtitles on Youtube.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich there are subtitles. But they are totally inadequate - at least at that place. They are only auto-generated and definitely missing > 50% of what is said

Comment: @Björn Friedrich: As a student of German I've found autogenerated subtitles to be useless. Maybe in 10 years the AI will have been trained up enough to correctly transliterate natural speech, but as of now it's still science fiction. I think It will depend on the language as well, with more popular languages coming first Meanwhile, text to voice, and text to text translation are usable if still not perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Joseph Goebbels (man in suit): "Also Fräulein Mimieux, kommen wir zum Geschäft." (so Miss Mimieux, let's talk business)

(French translation, then spoken over by the soldier, Schütze Frederick Zollner:)
Herr Dr. Goebbels, ich habe sie noch nicht eingeweiht. (Dr. Goebbels, I did not yet tell her)

Joseph Goebbels (man in suit): "Wenn sie nicht allzu blöd ist, hat sie es doch längst begriffen. Schließlich ist sie ja eine Kino-Betreiberin." then to the translator: "Übersetz das bitte!". (If she is not overly stupid, she will know already. She's a cinema owner/operator after all - Translate that please!)

Comment: Thank youuuuuuu

Comment: @ChanwitDitcharoen if you consider an answer helpful and the best answer, consider to accept it. Upvotes and accepting answers are the best way on SE to thank people :) - don't immediately accept the first answer. Waiting a day or few usually is a good idea as better answers can show up later than an hour or two after posting your question.